# Application cache not working when server unavailable: Applicaion Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache, application-cache

I'm working on a little project to create an offline application using HTML5, IndexedDB and Angular. I've been testing the application cache functionality by toggling air plane mode on my laptop and so far so good.

However, my requirements are that the application should be availble when the user is not connected to the VPN instead of not connected to the internet. I'm testing this by starting/stopping the applciation hosted in IIS, so I might still have a connection to the internet but not to the server that hosts the application. In this scenario I always get the error (in Chrome) "Applicaion Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (6)". FireFox doesn't give an error and IE just says Fatal AppCache Error.

I know why I get the error (= the manifest file cannot be fetched from the server), I'm just wondering if there is anything I can do to avoid the error? I've been looking at ways to override or prevent the swapcache/update events but no luck. Any idea if this can be fixed and how?

Comment: can't you still use the webapp despite the error?

Comment: I think it stops script execution, but I'm still testing this. It's an option if it doesn't cause problems but ideally I would need a workaround.

Comment: on the face of it, your question goes against the laws of physics. the event/message is to let your app know that it's not gotten updates this time, not that it cannot continue. if you don't need to take some action at that point (maybe load some defaults, trigger a visible offline badge on the UI, etc), then you can safely ignore the "error"; it's business as usual.